# Poker hand identifier

Tags: haskell, playing-cards

Inspired by [this post](https://github.com/themattrix/poker_hand) (along with a number of other people by the looks of it), I created a poker hand identifier with a very similar format. Note that the syntax of the hands is a little different to make parsing easier - rather than "A:C K:C Q:C J:C 10:C", the input is of the form "[(A,C),(K,C),(Q,C),(J,C),(10,C)]".

The code works correctly for the sample inputs in the post, I'm more concerned about coding style and elegance. For example, I've used pointfree style and the `Maybe` monad (with `guard` and `isJust`) where I can so it's not very consistent. `getPair` doesn't seem very nice but it does save on a reasonable amount of boilerplate; am I right in thinking that returning `((Card,Card),Hand)` instead of `(Card,Card,Hand)` would make the pattern matching on it slightly nicer?

Example usage:

```
identifyHand "[(5,H),(5,D),(A,S),(10,D),(5,C)]" == "Three of a kind"
identifyHand "[(2,H),(3,H),(4,H),(5,H),(A,D)]"  == "High card: A"
```

## pokerhands.hs

```
import Data.List (sort, deleteBy, nub)
import Data.Maybe (isJust)
import Control.Monad (guard)
import Data.Function (on)

main :: IO ()
main = readFile "hands.txt" >>= putStrLn . unlines . map identifyHand . lines

-------------------------
-- Types and instances --
-------------------------

type Hand = [Card]
type Card = (Value,Suit)

-- Num n is valid for 2 <= n <= 10
data Value = Num Int | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
    deriving (Eq, Ord)

-- Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades
data Suit = C | D | H | S
    deriving (Read, Show, Eq)

data Combination
    = Royal
    | StraightFlush
    | Four
    | FullHouse
    | Flush
    | Straight
    | Three
    | TwoPair
    | Pair
    | High Value

instance Show Value where
    show (Num n) = show n
    show Jack    = "J"
    show Queen   = "Q"
    show King    = "K"
    show Ace     = "A"

instance Read Value where
   -- readsPrec :: Int -> String -> [(Value,String)]
   -- p.s. I do not really know how readsPrec works
   readsPrec _ ('J':xs) = [(Jack ,xs)]
   readsPrec _ ('Q':xs) = [(Queen,xs)]
   readsPrec _ ('K':xs) = [(King ,xs)]
   readsPrec _ ('A':xs) = [(Ace  ,xs)]
   readsPrec _ xs = case reads xs of
       ((n,xs'):_) | n >= 2 && n <= 10
                       -> [(Num n,xs')]
       _               -> []

instance Show Combination where
    show Royal         = "Royal flush"
    show StraightFlush = "Straight flush"
    show Four          = "Four of a kind"
    show FullHouse     = "Full house"
    show Flush         = "Flush"
    show Straight      = "Straight"
    show Three         = "Three of a kind"
    show TwoPair       = "Two pair"
    show Pair          = "One pair"
    show (High v)      = "High card: " ++ show v

-----------------------
-- Identifying hands --
-----------------------

identifyHand :: String -> String
identifyHand s = case reads s of
    ((h,_):_) | nub h /= h   -> "ERROR: Duplicate card"
              | length h < 5 -> "ERROR: Too few cards"
              | length h > 5 -> "ERROR: Too many cards"
              | otherwise    -> show (getComb h)
    _                        -> "ERROR: parse error"

getComb :: Hand -> Combination
getComb h
    | isStraight h
      && isFlush h  = if isRoyal h then Royal else StraightFlush
    | isFour h      = Four
    | isFullHouse h = FullHouse
    | isFlush h     = Flush
    | isStraight h  = Straight
    | isThree h     = Three
    | isTwoPair h   = TwoPair
    | isPair h      = Pair
    | otherwise     = High . maximum . map fst $ h

isRoyal :: Hand -> Bool
-- h must be a straight flush
isRoyal h = maximum (map fst h) == Ace

isStraight :: Hand -> Bool
isStraight = isConsecutive . sort . map fst

isFlush :: Hand -> Bool
isFlush h = all (x==) xs
    where (x:xs) = map snd h

isFour :: Hand -> Bool
isFour h = isJust $ do
    ((c1,_),(_,_),h') <- getPair h
    ((c2,_),(_,_),_ ) <- getPair h'
    guard $ c1 == c2

isFullHouse :: Hand -> Bool
isFullHouse h = isJust $ do
    (_,_,h') <- getPair h
    guard (isThree h')

isThree :: Hand -> Bool
isThree h = case getPair h of
    Just ((c1,_),(c2,_),h') -> any (`elem` [c1,c2]) (map fst h')
    Nothing                 -> False

isTwoPair :: Hand -> Bool
isTwoPair h = isJust $ do
    (_,_,h') <- getPair h
    getPair h'

isPair :: Hand -> Bool
isPair = isJust . getPair

----------------------
-- Helper functions --
----------------------

getPair :: Hand -> Maybe (Card,Card,Hand)
-- if the hand has at least one pair then the two cards
-- from the first pair are removed from the hand and then
-- that pair and the remaining hand are returned
getPair ((c,s):h) = case lookup c h of
     Just s' -> Just ((c,s),(c,s')
                     ,deleteBy ((==) `on` fst) (c,undefined) h)
     Nothing -> getPair h
getPair [] = Nothing

isConsecutive :: [Value] -> Bool
isConsecutive (x:x1:xs) = isNext x x1 && isConsecutive (x1:xs)
isConsecutive _ = True

isNext :: Value -> Value -> Bool
isNext (Num 10) Jack     = True
isNext (Num n)  (Num n') = n' == n+1
isNext Jack     Queen    = True
isNext Queen    King     = True
isNext King     Ace      = True
isNext _        _        = False
```

Comment: Don't forget about the "wheel" straight - A 2 3 4 5.

Comment: @user5402 To some that rule is optional

Comment: ***FYI:*** `Royal` is a subtype of `StraightFlush`. A `Royal` represents one of the **4** highest ranked instances of the **36** possible `StraightFlushes`. The arbitrary distinction has always driven me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Some more ideas - you could have an `Enum` instance / `isNext` derived without all the boilerplate if you defined `Value` either as

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
newtype Value = Val Int
   deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum, Bounded)
```

or as

```
data Value = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten 
           | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum)
```

depending on whether that seems like a good idea to you or not. The latter representation is better than it might appear at first - after all, the `Enum` instance allows you to easily convert to and from numerical values using `toEnum` / `fromEnum`, so you don't have to change your `Read` & `Show` instances much.

---

Also, I feel like your hand matching could be simplified if you preprocessed the hand a bit:

```
getComb :: Hand -> Combination
getComb h
     ...
  where hg = sortBy (compare `on` length) $
             groupBy ((==) `on` fst) $
             sortBy (compare `on` fst) h
```

This "grouped" hand representation has the nice property that you can write hand group checks like follows:

```
type HandGrouped = [[Card]]

isPair :: HandGrouped -> Maybe HandGrouped
isPair ([_,_]:xs) = Just xs
isPair _          = Nothing

isTwoPair :: HandGrouped -> Maybe HandGrouped
isTwoPair h = isPair h >>= isPair
```

---

Hm, but isn't your implementation actually quite incomplete? Right now, you can't distinguish between ace-high and jack-high straights, for example, or equal pairs with different kickers.

Here's a quick (untested) sketch of how I think you could build the program to have all the mentioned features, using slightly more involved trickery:

```
-- Low-value combinations first, so it works well with Value
data Combination = HighCard | Pair Value | TwoPair Value Value | ...
    deriving Ord

-- Combination, remaining cards / kicker. Implicit Ord instance gives
-- you card value order!
type Evaluation = (Combination, HandGrouped)

getPair, getTwoPair :: HandGrouped -> Maybe Evaluation
getPair ([c,_]:xs) = Just (Pair (fst c), xs)
getPair _          = Nothing
getTwoPair xs      = do
  (Pair v1, xs') <- getPair xs
  (Pair v2, xs'') <- getPair xs'
  return (TwoPair v1 v2, xs'')

getCombination :: HandGrouped -> Maybe Evaluation
getCombination xs = msum
  [ ...
  , getTwoPair xs
  , getPair xs
  , return (HighCard, xs)
  ]
```

Using that `msum` returns the first value in the list that is not `Nothing`.

Answer (score 1):

So here is my version of your program. It took some pragmas, but I hope it is alright?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances,IncoherentInstances,ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.List (sort, deleteBy, nub)
import Data.Maybe (isJust)
import Control.Monad (guard)
import Data.Function (on)

main :: IO ()
main = readFile "hands.txt" >>= putStrLn . unlines . map identifyHand . lines

-------------------------
-- Types and instances --
-------------------------

type Hand = [Card]
type Card = (Value,Suit)

-- Num n is valid for 2 <= n <= 10
data Value = Num Int | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
    deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

I removed the Combination data type because it did not seem to be adding
any use to the program. Instead I modified the show to be more intelligent.

I also got rid of isNext because it is actually trying to do an Enum poorly. So
instead we have an Enum and a Bound (They are not completely necessary, but
going by the spirit of building the language in which to describe the problem
first, I would say they are justified.)

```
instance Enum Value where
  succ King = Ace
  succ Queen = King
  succ Jack = Queen
  succ (Num 10) = Jack
  succ (Num i) = Num $ succ i

  pred Ace = King
  pred Queen = Jack
  pred King = Queen
  pred Jack = (Num 10)
  pred (Num i) = Num (pred i)

  fromEnum (Num i) = i
  fromEnum v = succ $ fromEnum (pred v)
  toEnum i | i <= 10 = Num i
  toEnum i = pred $ toEnum (succ i)

instance Bounded Value where
  minBound = Num 2
  maxBound = Ace

data Suit = C | D | H | S
    deriving (Read, Show, Eq)

instance Show Value where
    show (Num n) = show n
    show Jack    = "J"
    show Queen   = "Q"
    show King    = "K"
    show Ace     = "A"

instance Read Value where
   readsPrec _ ('J':xs) = [(Jack ,xs)]
   readsPrec _ ('Q':xs) = [(Queen,xs)]
   readsPrec _ ('K':xs) = [(King ,xs)]
   readsPrec _ ('A':xs) = [(Ace  ,xs)]
   readsPrec _ xs = case reads xs of
       ((n,xs'):_) | n >= 2 && n <= 10
                       -> [(Num n,xs')]
       _               -> []
```

So, our show changes.

```
instance Show [Card] where
    show h
      | isStraight  h
        && isFlush  h   = if isRoyal h then "Royal" else "Straight flush"
      | isFour      h   = "Four of a kind"
      | isFullHouse h   = "Full house"
      | isFlush     h   = "Flush"
      | isStraight  h   = "Straight"
      | isThree     h   = "Three of a kind"
      | isTwoPair   h   = "Two pair"
      | isPair      h   = "One pair"
      | otherwise       = "High card: " ++ show (maximum . map fst $ h)

-----------------------
-- Identifying hands --
-----------------------

identifyHand :: String -> String
identifyHand s = case reads s of
    ((h::Hand,_):_) | nub h /= h   -> "ERROR: Duplicate card"
              | length h < 5 -> "ERROR: Too few cards"
              | length h > 5 -> "ERROR: Too many cards"
              | otherwise    -> show h
    _                        -> "ERROR: parse error"

isRoyal :: Hand -> Bool
isRoyal h = maximum (map fst h) == Ace

isStraight :: Hand -> Bool
isStraight = isConsecutive . sort . map fst
```

When possible, define generic methods, and use them

```
isFlush :: Hand -> Bool
isFlush = same . (map snd)

same :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
same = (1 ==) . length . nub
```

I found isThree to be rather similar to isFour. So in the interests of
consistency they are defined similarly

```
isFour :: Hand -> Bool
isFour h = isJust $ do
    ((c1,_),(_,_),h') <- getPair h
    ((c2,_),(_,_),_ ) <- getPair h'
    guard $ c1 == c2

isThree :: Hand -> Bool
isThree h = isJust $  do
    ((c1,_),x,h') <- getPair h
    ((_,_),(c2,_),_ ) <- getPair (x:h')
    guard $ c1 == c2
```

I like the cleanliness of chaining rather than the do notation, but that is
subjective.

```
isFullHouse :: Hand -> Bool
isFullHouse h = isJust $ return h >>= getPair >>= (guard . isThree . remHand)

isTwoPair :: Hand -> Bool
isTwoPair h = isJust $ return h >>= getPair >>= (getPair . remHand)

isPair :: Hand -> Bool
isPair = isJust . getPair

----------------------
-- Helper functions --
----------------------
```

Did a little bit of modifications here too. I feel this is more idiomatic than
your version.

```
-- if the hand has at least one pair then the two cards
-- from the first pair are removed from the hand and then
-- that pair and the remaining hand are returned
getPair :: Hand -> Maybe (Card,Card,Hand)
getPair (x:h) = case h'' of
    [] -> Nothing
    _  -> Just (x, head h'', h' ++ tail h'')
  where (h',h'') = break (\ x' -> fst x' == fst x) h

remHand :: (Card,Card,Hand) -> Hand
remHand (_,_,h) = h
```

A side benefit is isConsecutive which is now applicable for any arrays that have
Enum defined for their elements.

```
isConsecutive :: (Enum a, Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
isConsecutive (x:xs) 
  | x == maxBound = False
  | otherwise = succ x == (head xs) && isConsecutive xs

-- isConsecutive (x:xs) = snd $ foldl (\(x,b) y -> (y, succ x == y && b)) (x,True) xs
```

I would encourage you to add a quickcheck to these functions.

Comment: A note on `isConsecutive`: `succ` is undefined for `maxBound` - your code would throw an error for, say, a pair of aces. I think you need to add an explicit check for `maxBound` there.