# Poker Hand Kata

Tags: haskell, playing-cards

Similar to, but distinct from [Poker hand identifier](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12112/poker-hand-identifier). I'm working towards solving [this kata](http://codingdojo.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?KataPokerHands). The below code doesn't print the result yet, and it reads hand strings rather than game strings.

Take 4:

```
import Data.String
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

data Rank = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine 
          | Ten | Jack | Queen | King | Ace 
          deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Bounded, Enum)

instance Read Rank where
  readsPrec _ value = 
    let tbl = zip "23456789TJQKA" [Two .. Ace]
    in case lookup (head value) tbl of
      Just r -> [(r, tail value)]
      Nothing -> error $ "Invalid rank: " ++ value

data Suit = H | C | D | S deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)

data Card = Card { rank :: Rank, suit :: Suit } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance Read Card where
  readsPrec _ [r, s] = [(Card (read [r]) (read [s]), "")]
  readsPrec _ value = error $ "Invalid card: " ++ value

data Hand = Hand { handRank :: HandRank, cards :: [Card] } 
          deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

instance Read Hand where
  readsPrec _ value =
    [(Hand (getHandRank res) res, "")]
    where res = reverse . sort . map read $ words value

data HandRank = HighCard [Rank] 
              | Pair [Rank]
              | TwoPair [Rank]
              | ThreeOfAKind [Rank]
              | Straight [Rank]
              | Flush [Rank]
              | FullHouse [Rank] 
              | FourOfAKind [Rank] 
              | StraightFlush [Rank]
              deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data GameOutcome = Winner String Hand | Tie deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance Show GameOutcome where
  show o = case o of
    Winner player hand -> player ++ " wins with " ++ show (handRank hand)
    Tie -> "Tie"

isFlush :: [Card] -> Bool
isFlush = (1==) . length . group . map suit

isStraight :: [Card] -> Bool
isStraight cards = 
  let rs = sort $ map rank cards
      run = [(head rs) .. (last rs)]
  in rs == run

getHandRank :: [Card] -> HandRank
getHandRank cards =
  let ranks = map rank cards
      rankGroups = sortByLen $ group ranks
      relevantRanks = map (!!0) rankGroups
      handRank = case cards of
        _ | isFlush cards && isStraight cards  -> StraightFlush
          | has4 rankGroups                        -> FourOfAKind
          | has3 rankGroups && has2 rankGroups -> FullHouse
          | isFlush cards                          -> Flush
          | isStraight cards                       -> Straight
          | has3 rankGroups                        -> ThreeOfAKind 
          | countGroupsOf 2 rankGroups == 2      -> TwoPair
          | has2 rankGroups                        -> Pair
          | otherwise                              -> HighCard
  in handRank relevantRanks

winner :: Hand -> Hand -> GameOutcome
winner h1 h2 =
  case compare h1 h2 of
    GT -> Winner "Player 1" h1
    LT -> Winner "Player 2" h2
    EQ -> Tie

-------------------------------
-- General Utility Functions --
-------------------------------
hasGroupOf :: Int -> [[a]] -> Bool
hasGroupOf n groups = n `elem` map length groups
has4 = hasGroupOf 4
has3 = hasGroupOf 3
has2 = hasGroupOf 2

countGroupsOf :: Int -> [[a]] -> Int
countGroupsOf n groups = length $ filter (\g -> length g == n) groups

sortByLen :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
sortByLen = sortBy (flip $ comparing length)
```

- Added comparison function
- Fixed a bug relating to improper sorting in some situations (replaced `nub` with `relevantRanks` in `getHandRank`
- Ran it through `hlint`

My only experience with Haskell so far is some playing around with `Parsec` and a few half-read-throughs of [WYAS48](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours), so please be obnoxious about style issues.

All feedback welcome, but I would particularly like to ask

1. Are there built-ins/better implementations of the "General Utility" functions defined at the bottom?
2. Is there a clearer or more succinct way of writing `Read Rank`?
3. Is there a clearer or more flexible way of writing `getHandRank`, with particular emphasis on closely connecting those predicates with the `data` entry?

Answer (score 3):

It's generally a good idea to give explicit type signatures for your top level definitions. It helps your code's readers (e.g. us) understand your code.

`hasGroupOf` looks perfectly clear (save for the missing type signature), but I'd write the other two like this:

```
import Data.Ord (comparing)

countGroupsOf :: Int -> [a] -> Int
countGroupsOf n groups = length $ filter (\g -> length g == n) groups

sortByLen :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
sortByLen = sortBy (flip $ comparing length)
```

Actually, for that last one, I'd probably want lists of equal length to sort in a predictable order:

```
import Data.Monoid

sortByLen :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
sortByLen = sortBy (mconcat [flip $ comparing length, compare])
```

(You are expected to know that `Ordering` is a monoid, and that `a -> b` is a monoid when `b` is a monoid. The monoid I'm using is `[a] -> [a] -> Ordering`.)

Comment: I took your advice on the type signatures and simplified functions (note that `countGroupsOf` actually has a type signature of `Int -> [[a]] -> Int`; I assume this only matters because we're mapping `length` over the contents of that argument). The monadic `sortByLen` threw me a type error, and I'm not *entirely* sure what it's doing, so I stuck with your first version.

Answer (score 2):

I think your `instance Read Card` can be improved. There's no reason to use `length` if you just want to know whether the length is 2 or not 2. If the length is 2 then `value` is [r,s] (`String` is just `[Char]`), so you can write

```
readsPrec _ [r,s] = ...
readsPres _ _     = ...
```

Then you can just do `read [r]` and `read [s]`. I don't think you have to specify `(read r :: Rank)` either. The compiler should be able to figure it out from the way you're using it. And of course if you know that `value` is of length 2, you know what `drop 2 value` is.

I'm kind of sleepy so I apologize for any horrible mistakes I've made in this answer.

Comment: Right on all counts

Answer (score 2):

Your`rankGroups` list is sorted by the size of the group. If you reverse sort it you can use:

```
case rankGroups of
  (4:_)      -> -- four of a kind
  (3:2:_)    -> -- full house
  (3:_)      -> -- trips but not a full house
  (2:2:_)    -> -- two pair
  (2:_)      -> -- a pair but not two pair
  (1:_)      -> -- check for straights and flushes
```